# How do you iterate and update a numpy array to solve a system of linear equations of form Ax=B?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numerical-methods

So I am looking to solve a system of equations in python 3.7 with numpy. However, I need to solve the system of equations at the end of each iteration. During the iterations, it will solve some equations that will make up the contents of A and B to find x in the form of Ax=B. Upon solving for x I need to save these values to then solve the underlying equations for the following iteration to be reimplemented in A and B.

I have tried a more linear approach to solving the problem but it is not good for my end goal of solving the equation attached in the image. What I have done so far has also been attached below:

```
i = 0


while (y[i] >= 0 ):                     #Object is above water
    t[i+1] = t[i] + dt

    vx[i+1] = vx[i] + dt * ax[i]       #Update the velocities
    vy[i+1] = vy[i] + dt * ay[i]

    v_ax[i+1] = (vx[i]*np.sin(phi/180*np.pi)) - (vy[i]*np.cos(phi/180*np.pi))
    v_nor[i+1] = (vx[i]*np.cos(phi/180*np.pi)) + (vy[i]*np.sin(phi/180*np.pi))

    F_wnor[i+1] = (Cd_a * A_da * rho_air * (v_nor[i] - v_wind*np.sin(phi/180*np.pi)) * abs(v_nor[i] - v_wind*np.sin(phi/180*np.pi)))/2
    F_wax[i+1] = (Cd_a * A_da * rho_air * (v_ax[i] - v_wind*np.sin(phi/180*np.pi)) * abs(v_ax[i] - v_wind*np.sin(phi/180*np.pi)))/2

    F_wx[i+1] = (-F_wax[i] * np.sin(phi/180*np.pi)) - (F_wnor[i] * np.cos(phi/180*np.pi))
    F_wy[i+1] = (F_wax[i] * np.cos(phi/180*np.pi)) - (F_wnor[i] * np.sin(phi/180*np.pi))

    ax[i+1] = F_wx[i]/M  
    ay[i+1] = (F_wx[i]/M) - g

    y[i+1] = (y[i]+dt*vy[i])
    x[i+1] = (x[i]+dt*vx[i])

    i = i + 1


j = i 
#under water velocities

# if y(t)>0: M*z'' = M.g - Fb + Fd + Fm

while (y[j] <= 0 and y[j] > -10):

    if (abs(y[j]/r)< 2):
        theta_degree = 2 * np.arccos(1 - (abs(y[j])/r))
        theta = theta_degree/180*np.pi
        m = ((rho_water * r**2)/2) * (((2*(np.pi)**3*(1-np.cos(theta))) / ( 3 * (2*np.pi-theta)**2)) \
             + (np.pi * (1-np.cos(theta)*1/3)) + (np.sin(theta)) - (theta))

        dm_dz = ((rho_water * r)/np.sin(theta/2)) * (((2 * (np.pi)**3 / 3) * ((np.sin(theta) / (2*np.pi - theta)**2) \
                  + (2 * (1-np.cos(theta)) / (2*np.pi - theta )**3))) + (np.pi * np.sin(theta) / 3) + np.cos(theta) - 1)

        A_i = (r**2)/2 * (theta - np.sin(theta))

        F_m[j] = - m * ay[j] - dm_dz * np.max(vy)*vy[j]

        F_uwater[j] = (M * g) - (rho_water * A_i * g) - (Cd_y * rho_water * r * vy[j] * abs(vy[j]))



    else:
        m = np.pi * rho_water * r**2

        dm_dz = 0

        A_i = np.pi * r**2

        F_m[j] = - m * ay[j] - dm_dz * vy[j]**2

        F_uwater[j] = (M * g) - (rho_water * A_i * g) - (Cd_y * rho_water * r * vy[j] * abs(vy[j]))

        print("Fully submerged")


    t[j+1] = t[j] + dt

    vx[j+1] = vx[j] + dt * ax[j]       #Update the velocities
    vy[j+1] = vy[j] + dt * ay[j]

    ax[j+1] = F_wx[j]/M  
    ay[j+1] = (F_uwater[j] + F_m[j]/M)

    y[j+1] = (y[j]+dt*vy[j])
    x[j+1] = (x[j]+dt*vx[j])

    print(y[j])

    j = j + 1
```

I do not know how to go about this and help for getting started would be greatly appreciated!.

The problem I am trying to solve can be seen more clearly in the picture attached. [System of equations I am trying to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diTHr.png)

Comment: Why are you using the first order Euler method and not a proper ODE integration method? Explicit Euler is good as an educational introduction to numerical methods, but not for practical use.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I plan on using either RK4 or RK5 but I wanted to make sure I was along the right lines first

Comment: Prepare it for `solve_ivp`. This is one example where the event mechanism in its current form can be very useful. Are the phase boundaries the only equations you have to solve? I do not see where in the current code you establish a linear system.

Comment: @LutzLehmann okay I will try use solve_ivp and see how that goes! By saying it was made more linear I meant that the way it was being solved instead of me collecting the components of acceleration and the corresponding forces into vectors with a mass matrix. It is a problem based on free fall and how an object reacts once it has hit water and it’s subsequent motion under the water due to hydrostatic forces and buoyancy being included.

Comment: Could it be that your equations take a detour too many? What is the use of `phi` in the free-fall equation, where is it defined, does not the forth-and-back transformation cancel out, that is, is it possible to get all those values without computing an angle? The same for the other phases.